# How to add all empty folders on git from local

Tags: github

How to add all empty folders on github from local

To add files we generaly use git add folder/subfolder/file.txt
but I want on folder like git add folder/subfolder/subfolder-2

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an empty folder to git. Some people opt to create a `.gitignore` or a `.gitkeep` file inside the directory.